# Forms - How to pass custom options to CollectionType child in Symfony 4

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections, formbuilder

I want to pass some custom options to my class "PointageType" from the class "AffaireType", for example the id of the current user to create a query in my class "PointageType".

I tried to pass the id of my user in 'entry_options' of my buildForm() function in AffaireType but it shows me an error :

> The option "id" does not exist. Defined options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "allow_file_upload", "attr", "attr_translation_parameters", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "block_prefix", "by_reference", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "help", "help_attr", "help_html", "help_translation_parameters", "inherit_data", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "label_translation_parameters", "mapped", "method", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "required", "translation_domain", "trim", "upload_max_size_message", "validation_groups".

My AffaireType class :

```
class AffaireType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('numAffaire');
        $builder->add('descAffaire');
        $builder->add('pointages', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => PointageType::class,
            'entry_options' => array(
                'id' => 8,
            ),
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Affaires::class,
        ]);
    }

}
```

My PointageType class :

```
class PointageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('heurePointage');
        //I want to do the query here
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
          'data_class' => Pointage::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I think this code works in Symfony 2/3 but how i can do this with Symfony 4.3 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add an option to a form type, use the OptionsResolver in `configureOptions`:

```
$resolver->setRequired(['id']); // for required options, with no default
// OR
$resolver->setDefaults(['id' => null]); // for optional options, that can be set
```

in your case, this would have to be set in `PointageType::configureOptions`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :)